# How do I fix Axios Baseurl bug for Node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express, axios

I made a program for a device.
We used vue on the front end and express on the back end.
And we use axios to fetch API

When I localize the baseurl related to axios, I can't connect to the site through my phone (Other device), as shown below, and it gives an axios error.
127.0.0.1:6060
And when I set the baseurl to the address of the server itself, it works, but it is interrupted,
and I don't want to change the address once on each device.

```js
import axios from 'axios';
const data = require("../../app/env.json")

axios.defaults.baseURL = data.baseURL ; //baseURL = 127.0.0.1:6060 || 192.168.1.100:6060
axios.defaults.headers = { 'Contect-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
```

I want a way that I don't have to set the baseurl every time

axios error:

```json
{
    "message": "Network Error",
    "name": "AxiosError",
    "stack": "AxiosError: Network Error\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:155:14)",
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "adapter": "xhr",
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {},
        "headers": {
            "Contect-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            "Authorization": "xxx"
        },
        "baseURL": "http://192.168.1.100:6060",
        "method": "get",
        "url": "api/alarms"
    },
    "code": "ERR_NETWORK",
    "status": null
}
```

At first, I thought that the problem was with the backend of the program, and I changed the cors a little and changed the middlewares, but it didn't make a difference and I could connect to the backend with my phone, and now I guess the problem is with the frontend and axios.

Comment: Could you please give env.json file snippet for clearifing question?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is the localhost address.  It is the address used by every device to connect to itself.  Unless the backend is also running on your phone it won't connect.  It's very important to understand localhost as a developer. Try researching it, there's some good articles explaining it, e.g. [this one here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/127-0-0-1-localhost)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cant access the localhost address on your phone. You have to define baseUrl for each environment separately (Eg. local, Dev, Production). To do this, simply create env files for each environment. In this case, one for local, and one for Production.

**.env.local:**

```
VUE_APP_BASE_URL=http://192.168.1.100:6060
```

**.env.production:**

```
VUE_APP_BASE_URL=https://your-production-url.com
```

Install and configure dotenv:

```
npm install dotenv --save
```

Now, you can load the environment-specific variables using dotenv

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

// Load environment-specific variables using dotenv
require('dotenv').config({ path: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '.env.production' : '.env.local' });

// Set the baseURL using the loaded environment variable
axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL;
axios.defaults.headers = { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' };
```